# Angular create project results in various console warnings

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

The solution given to earlier similar posts does not work for me.

I am new to Angular development and trying to learn from scratch. I am facing issue when I am trying to create my first app.

**Environment**

1. Windows 10
2. Angular latest version installation using GitBash
3. Node version: v12.14.0
4. NPM version: 6.13.4
5. Angular CLI version: 8.3.21

**Issue**

1. Given the command to install new project.

> ng new test

2. After some times it generates the below error.

   > npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
3. I was trying to quit. But after went through different posts I came to know that, installation will be proceed without any problem. I follow it. Finally installed successfully.
4. But at the end before successful installation message it generates a lots of messages on core-js postinstall, npm WARN, 0 vulnerabilities, warning etc.

**Here is the message at the end.**

```
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1193 packages from 1051 contributors and audited 18835 packages in 279.874s

21 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .editorconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in angular.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in browserslist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/protractor.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.po.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/tsconfig.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in karma.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.module.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.prod.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/polyfills.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/styles.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/test.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.app.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.spec.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tslint.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    Successfully initialized git.



 ng serve
i ?wds?: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ?wds?: webpack output is served from /
i ?wds?: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 47.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.71 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.81 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-12-26T14:34:42.939Z - Hash: 697612d9c3732f0363f0 - Time: 11060ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ?wdm?: Compiled successfully.
i ?wdm?: Compiling...

Date: 2019-12-26T14:51:49.861Z - Hash: 697612d9c3732f0363f0
5 unchanged chunks

Time: 14395ms
i ?wdm?: Compiled successfully.
```

I want to know why such the core-js and other issues are given. Is there any fault in my system and environment. Or, there is some installation issue on NodeJS. Or, is it a simple and ignoring issue, that can happen to anyone.

Comment: plz check your package.json. i think some packages not installed.

Comment: There is nothing to resolve here. These are all warning. Move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `npm update` in your project.

Comment: I have updated the npm, but still there is no improvement. Initially I do not have this warning, but since few days back, it occurs. My concern is why this is happened and how to overcome this.

Comment: Irrespective of the warning it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

New to this myself - but did some digging. Found a bug logged with angular CLI folks:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16576

The fix is in, but it looks like this is in major version 9 RC-7 I think.
Would be nice to know what to do if you are committed to using 8 until 9 is stable...